# can an IP be mapped to another IP in windows?

Tags: windows, ip, netsh

Can I map 146.112.61.106 IP address to my 127.0.0.1 adress ?

so when I type 146.112.61.106 I got redirected to 127.0.0.1 ?
(some netsh command maybe ?)

Comment: Yes, is indeed a duplicate, and is answered here: http://superuser.com/questions/363036/how-to-map-an-ip-adress-to-localhost

Answer (score 1):

You could add that IP to your network card as a second IP with a netmask of 255.255.255.255. That should have a similar effect.

Answer (score 1):

you can run a DNS server on your machine and add both IPs assign them to same location.
there is a tutorial here to how to install BIND for home user.
[BIND for home user](http://www.brennan.id.au/08-Domain_Name_System_BIND.html)

Comment: i updated my answer.